# Application X509 Certificate = IIS website Certificate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, certificate, x509certificate

I have my webapplication currently set as to use a specific Certificate. Now by the `ByTimeValid` member (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype(v=vs.110).aspx).

What I would like to have this changed to work with the SSL Certificate setting in IIS 8 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWiWw.png

I need a replacement for `ByTimeValid` wich will have as only condition to use the IIS Certificate.

Any member in the class that can give me this?